# Procedure in tcl: no return statement, still getting a return value?

Tags: function, tcl, procedure, tclsh

I'm new to `tcl`, and would like to get some understanding of how `return` statements work in the language. Take the following code, for instance:

```
proc add name {
  set name [expr $name+2]
}

set y 5
puts [add $y]
```

I was surprised to find that this actually prints the value `7` to my terminal. I was expecting nothing to print out since I have not included a `return` statement in my procedure.

When I do include a return statement, it seems to override this strange default behavior:

```
proc add name {
  set name [expr $name+2]
  return hello
}

set y 5
puts [add $y]
```

The above will indeed return hello. But what does it do with the `7`?

Why does the procedure still return a `7` even if I have no return statement? Why does it then override this behavior when I do provide a return statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't explicitly `return` a value, the value of the last statement executed in the proc will be returned. This is documented at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.html at the end of the DESCRIPTION section.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit confusing that the docs also state that "The proc command returns an empty string". Not sure what that's about, but I did find the section you were referring to.

Comment: The proc command is used to *define* a procedure, that operation returns an empty string.  *Calling* the procedure returns a value as explained in the answer.

Comment: Note that many commands have the empty string as their result. This can make it seem like nothing is being returned, but actually something always is. You can always put `return` in at the end of your procedure bodies if you want to be explicit. (Note that not requiring it makes this possible/easy: `proc function {name arguments body} {tailcall proc tcl::mathfunc::$name $args [list expr $body]}`; added fun for your expressions!)